# Is it Possible to Pass Additional Info to the EMR Cluster using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr, terraform

We are trying to create an AWS EMR Cluster using Terraform (v0.9.11) and wanted to know if there is a way to Pass Additional Info like below via Terraform -

```
{  
   'ami64':'ami-XXXXX',
   'amiHvm64':'ami-XXXXXXX',
   'customAMI':true,
   'hadoopConfigurationVersion':'4.0',
   'instanceAwsClientConfiguration':{  
      'proxyPort':8099,
      'proxyHost':'XXXXXXXX'
   }
}
```

Could anyone please help us with above query?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a way to terraform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if you are fine to use `configurations` in resource `aws_emr_cluster`

```
configurations = "test-fixtures/emr_configurations.json"
```

Save the JSON to `test-fixtures/emr_configurations.json`.

By the way, seems you need to change from single quotes to double quotes in your json data.

For the configuration usage, you need to read this document: [Amazon EMR Configuring Applications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html)

Refer:

[aws_emr_cluster - configurations](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html#configurations)

[Amazon EMR Configuring Applications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html)

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. I am using configurations in my terraform script. I am still not sure what Classification to use with the Inputs that i provided.

Comment: @RohitSarkar Thanks to accept my answer, did you fix your issue? If you did, could you update your question with the correct configuration json?

Comment: I am still not clear on what Classification to use with the Additional Info, as soon as i figure it out i will pass on the Details.

Comment: Quote: `The classification usually specifies the file name that you want modifying.`, will this be helpful?

Comment: @BMW, these aren't specifically in any file inside the instances. When you create the cluster, add an `unhide` query parameter and you will get an additional info box to appear. There we may provide the above JSON.